# Calling a Method Adjusting Marks

Tags: java, methods, call

I'm creating a grade manager for students  which organizes marks for one course using java.

```
Input Txt File:
Student Name     Student ID    Student Grades
Steven Jones     3456749       85,67,78,76
Lenny Thomas     2343738       56,75,57,98
```

I'm having trouble with creating a method that bell curves student grades based on this structure

If the current mark:

- is greater than or equal to 80% /the new mark is 110% of the new mark
- is greater than or equal to 65% /the new mark is 120% of the new mark
- is greater than or equal to 50% /the new mark is 130% of the new mark
- is greater than or equal to 0 /the new mark is 140% of the new mark

The method also has to output into a txt file in the same format as the input.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far? 

Show us some of your attempts and we'll try to find mistakes.

Comment: i'm having trouble starting to build the method, don't really know where to start.